# Is there a way to write html code along with java in eclipse for application development?

Tags: java, html, vs-web-application-project

I have started typing some basic code in java for airline reservation system using eclipse. Now I want to add frontend using html. Is there a way to combine these two codes and make use of only java? I know that javascript,java swing and many more exist but I want to use only java and html and css for frontend and combine with the java code I use. I will be using MYSQL for database

Answer (score 1):

1. In a java project press `Control + N` to get the new screen.
2. Then click `new file`.
3. Name it `index.html`

Now it is done!

If that does not work, download the java file and put it in a VS Code project with the html file